# Info.plist couldn't be removed on archive only

Tags: ios, swift, fmdb

I have an iOS objective-c app where I import a swift framework, this swift  contains a pod with the swift version of FMDB found here:

https://github.com/robertmryan/fmdb.git

When running the framework, all goes fine. When running the app in the simulator, all goes fine. But when I try to archive the app, xcode gives the error: No such module FMDB.

I'm at it for 2 days already and getting pretty fed up with it. Any ideas as to what it could be?

I tried, cleaning, reimporting, rebuilding, deep cleaning. Creating an entirely new app. Nothing seems to work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs,when FMDB is not integrated properly into project.
I suggest to delete all imported file at first,then follow below:

```
** Go to -> Finder -> Project directory.**

** And then Copy/import again to project by Xcode.**
```

Pod isn't necessary to use FMDB. You can use by Copy all FMDB files to your project and it creates automatically "Bridging-headerfile" for use FMDB functionality.

```
I suggest follow below link for a swift FMDB SQlite Database:
```

http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/use-sqlite-database-swift